# Can the WindsorContainer pass a object through the resolve tree when using a factory

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, windsor-facilities

I have a problem like this:

```
public interface IBaseVMFactory
{
  public BaseVm Create(TransientDependency otherVM);
}

public class BaseVM
{
   BaseVM(ChildVM1 child1, ChildVM2 child2)
}

public class ChildVM1
{
   ChildVM1(TransientDependency otherVM)
}
```

All my viewModels (..VM) needs to be transient. And I need for the childVM1 to get the same instance of otherVM as given to the factory.

I tried to register the BaseVm as ScopedLifestyle, and manually implementing the factory and passing the instance when resolving inside the scope.
But still I get a new instance of the otherVM when resolving.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Kjetil.

Comment: If it's transient, the container will create a new object each time. You need to set it PerWebRequest so that you got only one per web request, shared among all view model used. You can also use the .BoundTo when registering components, but this doesn't work for TypedFactory so it won't help you

Comment: Sorry, but this is in an WPF application. I've been trying with the BoundTo<> lifestyle as well, but as you pointed out, it won't work for factories. I was thinking if there is a way to inject the otherVm into the scope (If I use the Scoped lifestyle).

Comment: So you can try to make a CustomScope. This link can help you (I wroted the code in the wiki): http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Implementing%20custom%20scope.ashx

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was hoping to avoid that, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Why are you passing a TransientDependency on the Create method. Normally these should be injected by constructor/setter injection. Would you have a more complete sample with the registration that we can compile.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing your problem with Windsor 3.2 with the code below:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class SomeViewModel
    {
        public SomeViewModel(ISomeFactory factory)
        {
            var dependency1 = factory.CreateSomeDependency();
            var dependency2 = factory.CreateSomeDependency();

            Debug.Assert(dependency1 != dependency2);
            Debug.Assert(dependency1.Dep == dependency2.Dep);
        }
    }

    public class SomeDependency
    {
        private readonly DepDep _dep;

        public SomeDependency(DepDep dep)
        {
            _dep = dep;
        }

        public DepDep Dep
        {
            get { return _dep; }
        }
    }

    public class DepDep
    {
    }

    public interface ISomeFactory
    {
        SomeDependency CreateSomeDependency();
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
            container.Register(
                Component.For<SomeViewModel>().LifestyleTransient(),
                Component.For<SomeDependency>().LifestyleTransient(),
                Component.For<DepDep>().LifestyleBoundTo<SomeViewModel>(),
                Component.For<ISomeFactory>().AsFactory().LifestyleTransient()
                );
            container.Resolve<SomeViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

To my suprise this just works. So it seems that the factory is now taking over the scope of the context in which it is created. I hope this will help you.

Kind regards,
Marwijn.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I  agree that the transient dependency could have been avoided, but part of my code is very old and that kind of change isn't easy. The essence of my problem is that arguments passed to a factory isn't used when resolving indirect objects. I have a test project that I can share, where I'm trying to use a Custom scope.